# Integrating Discovery Miles With PayU

Tags: expresso-store, ee2, payment-gateway

I am busy integrating PayU payment gateway with an EE2 website and need to have payu integration on-site rather than off-page, but the client needs the customer to also pay with Discovery Miles, would there be a way to integrate Discovery Miles with the on-site integration of PayU?

I am using the Enterprise API for PayU and using Expresso-Store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with the PayU API but it shouldn't be a problem if their API allows on-site integration of Discovery Miles. You will just need to write a custom gateway that handles it based upon their API. Store's gateways are built on top of Omnipay ( https://github.com/omnipay/omnipay ) and you should be able to look at the include gateways as examples to get a good starting point. If you aren't comfortable with php I know that the team at Exp:resso also does custom gateway development.

Answer (score 2):

As Justin mentioned, if PayU supports this then it would certainly be possible.

Store (and the payment library Omnipay) supports both on-site and off-site gateways fine, so it's just a case of whether or not PayU supports this at their API level.